# How to Capture a click event on a radio button inside a table where the table rows are dynamically populated

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover marg30"
    id="mt_areaTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="tbrder" id="areatable1">
            <td class="biglable">Item 1</td>
            <td class="smalllable">
               <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <input type="radio"name="active1" class="areaYes"value="on">      <b>Yes</b>/label>
                  <input type="radio" name="active1" class="areaNo" autocomplete="off" value="off">  <b>No</b></label>
               </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

How can I Target the radio buttons with class areaYes and areaNo. The rows are getting added dynamically using the JS. I need to capture the on click event on the radio buttons and then get its name.

Comment: both name attr are same (active1).

Answer (score 1):

Try This :-

```
$(document.body).on("click",".areaYes,.areaNo",function(){
   alert($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

**OR**

```
$('#mt_areaTable').on("click",".areaYes,.areaNo",function(){
   alert($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

**Note:-** It's better to use `.change()` event instead of `.click()` for radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#mt_areaTable').on("click",".areaYes,.areaNo",function(){
  alert($(this).attr("name"));
 });
```

in your html both name value are same. so alert is active1. Change the name value.